# Docker Desktop for Windows cannot enable kubernetes with error x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, x509certificate, docker-desktop

I am trying to enable kubernetes for Docker Desktop. Kubernetes is however failing to start.

My log file shows:

```
cannot get lease for master node: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/docker-desktop": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/docker-desktop": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have NO_PROXY env var set already, and my hosts file has
`127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal` at the end, as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364587/docker-for-windows-stuck-at-kubernetes-is-starting)

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Below work around can help you resolve your issue.

You can solve this by

- Open ~.kube\config in a text editor
- Replace https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 to https://localhost:6443
- Try connecting again

From this [issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/waiting-for-kubernetes-to-be-up-and-running/47009)

- Reset Docker to factory settings
- Quit Docker
- Set the KUBECONFIG environment variable to %USERPROFILE%.kube\config
- Restart Docker and enable Kubernetes (still took a few minutes to start)

Attaching troubleshooting [blog1](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority/), [bolg2](https://velaninfo.com/rs/techtips/docker-certificate-authority/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

1. delete `$HOME/.kube/config`
2. Restart Docker Desktop
3. notice the `$HOME/.kube/config` is back and your `kubectl` should work

I have multiple `config*` files in `.kube` directory - these stay intact